# I want to upload larger files to azure storage from client side using react and using sas url by making the files into chunks

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-blob-storage

Actually i am stuck with creating chunks of files and uploading i was able to smaller files by making the PUT request to SAS urls but i was not able to figure out how to make these files intp chunks and create blob ids, in my use case i will be getting the chunks of files which i need to PUT to azure continuosly from a streaming after the streaming is complete i need to be able to get the complete video from the azure storage without corrupted form.

```js
import React from 'react';

class BlockUploadComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      file: null,
      blockIds: [],
      sasUrl: 'https://testvideos.blob.core.windows.net/uservideos/user_124/video_124/test.mp4?se=2023-05-13T16%3A38%3A05Z&sp=rc&sv=2022-11-02&sr=b&sig=ASqohkcsp/Q%2B6sQXrliweurhiueWLf%2BWjayRBoE7pj1KQg%3D',
    };
  }

  handleFileChange = (event) => {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    this.setState({ file });
  };

  handleUpload = async () => {
    const { file, sasUrl } = this.state;
    if (file) {
      const blockIds = await this.uploadFileBlocks(file, sasUrl);
      if (blockIds.length > 0) {
        this.commitBlocks(blockIds, sasUrl);
      }
    }
  };

  uploadFileBlocks = async (file, sasUrl) => {
    const blockSize = 4 * 1024 * 1024; // 4 MB block size
    const blockIds = [];
    let offset = 0;
    let blockId = 0;

    const reader = new FileReader();

    while (offset < file.size) {
      console.log(file.size)
      const blockData = file.slice(offset, offset + blockSize);
      const blockIdBase64 = btoa(`block-${blockId}`);
      console.log(blockIdBase64)
      await this.uploadBlock(blockIdBase64, blockData, sasUrl);
      blockIds.push(blockIdBase64);
      offset += blockSize;
      blockId++;
    }

    return blockIds;
  };

  uploadBlock = async (blockId, blockData, sasUrl) => {
    const requestUrl = `${sasUrl}&comp=block&blockid=${blockId}`;

    const response = await fetch(requestUrl, {
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
        'x-ms-blob-type': 'BlockBlob',
      },
      body: blockData,
    });

    if (response.ok) {
      console.log(`Block ${blockId} uploaded successfully.`);
    } else {
      console.error(`Error uploading block ${blockId}: ${response.statusText}`);
    }
  };

  commitBlocks = async (blockIds, sasUrl) => {
    const requestUrl = `${sasUrl}&comp=blocklist`;

    const blockListXml = `<BlockList>${blockIds
      .map((id) => `<Latest>${id}</Latest>`)
      .join('')}</BlockList>`;

    const response = await fetch(requestUrl, {
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
        'x-ms-blob-type': 'BlockBlob',
      },
      body: blockListXml,
    });

    if (response.ok) {
      console.log('Blocks committed successfully.');
    } else {
      console.error(`Error committing blocks: ${response.statusText}`);
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="file" onChange={this.handleFileChange} />
        <button onClick={this.handleUpload}>Upload</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default BlockUploadComponent;
```

Can i get any help with this ?